# How to pass jquery datepicker from template to view in python Django?

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, django, datepicker

I'm trying to use jquery-ui ,datepicker, to pass a date value to views.py where I have set query to pull data from mysql with pyodbc , but not sure what am I missing here. I'm new to Django. please help.

**template**

```
<form action = "" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</form>
```

**datepicker.js**

```
var stringDate = '2014-09-01T12:00:00+00:00'
var date = new Date(stringDate)
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: date,
    maxDate: "dateToday",
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',});
});
```

**views.py**

```
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    data_input = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())

def rev_dollar(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
      mydate = DateRangeFrom()
    else: 
      mydate = now.date().isoformat()

    con_a= pyodbc.connect('DSN=')
    sql = """
          select a, b from table 
          where date = %s , (mydate) 
          """
    pd.read_sql(sql, con_a)
```

what I want is if the form is not selected then **mydate = curdate()** <- in sql  , if selected date, then **mydate = '2014-10-01'** <- date pick

Comment: May I suggest setting a breakpoint with [`winpdb`](http://winpdb.org/).  Follow [these instructions for setting the breakpoint](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the very good documentation on Django forms.

At no point in your code are you passing the values of the POST request to the form. Also, you're not doing anything to get the date out of the form. So, not surprisingly, your code doesn't work.

Here's what you need to do:

```
mydate = now.date().isoformat()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DateRangeFrom(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mydate = form.cleaned_data('data_input')
```

Also, you need to set a `name` attribute for the field your HTML. Although since you've defined a form, you should be using that:

```
<form action = "" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.data_input }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In additional to @Daniel Roseman answer

```
data_input = forms.DateField(auto_now_add=True, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
```